# Almacenar variable de texto en un arreglo char

Tags: c++, punteros

Buenas estoy haciendo un problema que me dejaron en la universidad el cual me solicita desarrollar un programa el cual debe almacenar en una variable el texto : “Pablito clavó un clavito. ¿Qué clavito clavó Pablito?”  como arreglo char. Eso creo que ya está, luego me pide que mediante punteros recorrer la variable anterior y genere una nueva cadena donde se reemplace cualquier letra al azar, eso de punteros todavía no lo domino bien y lo que aparece en internet es más con arreglos y punteros de tipo entero, si conocen de alguna página o video que me pueda instruir se los agradecería esto es lo que tengo de código nada más porque no tengo idea de cómo hacer el resto.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char palabra[] = {"Pablito clav\242 un clavito. ¿Que clavito clav\242   Pablito?"};
    char *puntero = palabra;

    cout << puntero << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> mediante punteros recorrer la variable anterior y genere una nueva cadena donde se reemplace cualquier letra al azar

No indicas los criterios de reemplazo, así que haré un reemplazo según mis propios criterios, que son los siguientes:

- 1/4 parte de las letras podrían ser reemplazadas.
- El reemplazo será por letras entre la `a` y la `z`.
- Cualquier caracter (letras, espacios, puntuaciones, símbolos) es candidato a ser reemplazado.

Por otro lado, lo que tú llamas *cadena* es un arreglo de caracteres de tamaño estático finalizado con caracter nulo (`'\0'`), pero por comodidad lo llamaremos cadena.

```
char palabra[] = {"Pablito clav\242 un clavito. ¿Que clavito clav\242   Pablito?"};
char copia[sizeof(palabra)] = {};

std::random_device rd_reemplazar;
std::mt19937 generador_reemplazar(rd_reemplazar());
std::bernoulli_distribution reemplazar(0.25); // 25% de posibilidad de reemplazar

std::random_device rd_letra;
std::mt19937 generador_letras(rd_letra());
std::uniform_int_distribution<char> letra('a', 'z');

for (char *origen = palabra, *destino = copia, *final = palabra + sizeof(palabra); origen != final; ++origen, ++destino)
    *destino = reemplazar(generador_reemplazar) ? letra(generador_letras) : *origen;
```

En la versión de tu código no tienes lugar en que generar una nueva cadena, para ello hemos creado un arreglo llamado `copia` que será el destinatario de la cadena modificada, la longitud de este arreglo debe ser la misma que `palabra`, por eso se usa `sizeof(palabra)` como tamaño.

En el bucle del final de mi propuesta, creamos tres punteros a `char`:

- `origen`: apunta al principio de la cadena original (`palabra`).
- `destino`: apunta al principio de la cadena que contendrá la copia modificada (`copia`).
- `final`: apunta al final de la cadena original (`palabra`).

Cuando el puntero `origen` sea igual al puntero `final` sabremos que debemos dejar de copiar, por eso la segunda parte del bucle contiene la instrucción `origen != final` ya que copiaremos mientras el `origen` no sea el `final`, en caso contrario avanzaremos tanto el `origen` como el `destino` en la tercera instrucción del bucle: `++origen, ++destino`.

Por cada vuelta del bucle copiaremos **EN** la dirección apuntada por `destino` la letra original de `origen` o bien una letra generada al azar (un 25% de las veces); para conseguirlo debemos [des-referenciar el puntero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_de_desreferencia) para modificar (`*destino = ...`) o leer (`*origen`) su contenido.

---

Puedes ver un ejemplo del código que propongo [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/U19YSO1uw7bARn7X).